# bootstrap модальное окно не влазит содержимое

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Почему же не влазит именно содержимое с колонками, а обычный длинный текст без проблем. Что же я делаю не так?

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"　aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <img src="img/70.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7">
          <span class="package__number">70</span><br>
          <span>каналов</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span>
          Социальный пакет, в который вошли федеральные, познавательные, детские, спортивные, развлекательные каналы.
        </span>
        
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо блок с классом `.col-` размещать в блоке с классом `.row`

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
 </div>
.....
</div>
```

Пример

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"　aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <img src="img/70.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7">
          <span class="package__number">70</span><br>
          <span>каналов</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span>
          Социальный пакет, в который вошли федеральные, познавательные, детские, спортивные, развлекательные каналы.
        </span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="modal__desc">Эфирные</span><img src="img/icon3.png" alt="" class="modal__img">
          </div>
         <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Верно. Если .col- будет вне блока с классом .row, то из-за свойства float:left нижняя граница модального окна не будет поддерживать высоту по колонкам. А если оборачивать в .row, то из-за того, что там используется псевдокласс  ::after со свойством clear:both, нижняя граница окна начнет менять высоту по содержимому колонок.